# Read txt file line by line into char array C

Tags: c, fopen, scanf

I know this question has been asked a few times, but never in a way that helps me figure out my problem. Essentially, I am reading four text files, all single words separated by a new line, and wanting to store these in a char array. I first count the number of lines in the file and then create a new char array, but for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to get it to read correctly. The last two lines are just to test if it has read the entire file correctly and they always come back a NULL and the question mark symbol.

I want each line to be at the next index in the char array.

Any help would be awesome! Thank you ahead of time.

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void countAnagrams(char* fileName);

void main ()
{
    char *fileNames[] = {"AnagramA.txt","AnagramB.txt","AnagramC.txt","AnagramD.txt"};

    countAnagrams(fileNames[0]);
    countAnagrams(fileNames[1]);
    countAnagrams(fileNames[2]);
    countAnagrams(fileNames[3]);
}

void countAnagrams(char* fileName)
{
    int anagramCount = 0;
    int ch, lines = 0;  

    //Count number of lines in file
    FILE *myfile = fopen(fileName, "r");
    do
    {
        ch = fgetc(myfile);
        if(ch == '\n')
            lines++;
    }while(ch != EOF);

    char contents[lines];
    int i = 0;
    for(i=1;i<lines;i++)
    {
        fscanf(myfile,"%s",contents[i]);
    }
    fclose(myfile);

    printf("%.12s\n",fileName);
    printf("number of lines: %d\n", lines);

    printf("first thing: %s\n", contents[0]);
    printf("last thing: %s\n", contents[lines-1]);
}
```

Comment: `void main ()` is invalid on hosted environments.

Comment: "four text files, all single words separated by a new line," so that means `lines++;` occurs 3 times?

Comment: Enable warnings, your compiler wants a serious talk with you. And `char contents[lines];` is an array of `char`. Too many errors in your code.

Comment: After counting the lines your file pointer is at the end of the file. You need to close and reopen the file or simply `rewind`.

Comment: After `rewind()`, you may want `for(i=0;i<lines;i++)` or `for(i=0;i<=lines;i++)`

Comment: Im just using gedit to work with this. I am just trying to this working with reading the txt files into the arrays appropriately.

Comment: Your text files all contain a single word per line. So you could use `fgets` or `fscanf` to obtain each word (with string length restrictions), or to count the words before actually reading, after `rewind()` or re-opening the file.

Comment: `char contents[lines];` --> `char contents[lines+1][longest_word_length+1];`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a slight modification of your code that might help you.

The main points:

- You can use `getline()` instead of `fscanf()`. `fscanf()` can be used to read line-by-line, but it needs an explicit check for the end of line condition. `getline()` does this automatically.
- As kaylum pointed out, it's necessary to `rewind()` the file pointer back to the beginning of the file after counting the number of lines.

  ```
  #include <omp.h>                                                                                       
  #include <stdio.h>                                                                                     
  #include <stdlib.h>                                                                                    

  void countAnagrams(char* fileName);                                                                    

  void main ()                                                                                           
  {                                                                                                      
      char *fileNames[] = {"AnagramA.txt","AnagramB.txt","AnagramC.txt","AnagramD.txt"};                 

      countAnagrams(fileNames[0]);                                                                       
      countAnagrams(fileNames[1]);                                                                       
      countAnagrams(fileNames[2]);                                                                       
      countAnagrams(fileNames[3]);                                                                       
  }                                                                                                      

  void countAnagrams(char* fileName)                                                                     
  {                                                                                                      
      int anagramCount = 0;                                                                              
      int ch, lines = 0;                                                                                 

      //Count number of lines in file                                                                    
      FILE *myfile = fopen(fileName, "r");                                                               
      do                                                                                                 
      {                                                                                                  
          ch = fgetc(myfile);                                                                            
          if (ch == '\n')                                                                                
              lines++;                                                                                   
      } while (ch != EOF);                                                                               

      rewind(myfile);                                                                                    

      char *contents[lines];                                                                             
      int i = 0;                                                                                         
      size_t len = 0;                                                                                    
      for(i = 0; i < lines; i++)                                                                         
      {
          contents[i] = NULL;
          len = 0;                                                                                
          getline(&contents[i], &len, myfile);                                                           
      }                                                                                                  
      fclose(myfile);                                                                                    

      printf("%.12s\n",fileName);                                                                        
      printf("number of lines: %d\n", lines);                                                            

      printf("first thing: %s\n", contents[0]);                                                          
      printf("last thing: %s\n", contents[lines-1]);                                                     
  }
  ```

Comment: You need to set `contents[i]` to 0 (NULL) before using it in the call to [`getline()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getline.html), and I would set `len = 0;` on each iteration too.  That way, `getline()` knows it needs to allocate each time.  With indeterminate values in `content` entries and an increasing length in `len`, you have a recipe for major unpleasantness.

Comment: If the text file does not end with ` `'\n'`, `contents[lines]` will be 1 too small.

Comment: Thanks. Added the initializations.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is `char contents[lines]` and then `fscanf(myfile,"%s",contents[i])` and the `printf`-s after. `contents[i]` is `char` type, and you want to read an array of chars into one char. `contents` needs to be declared as `char* contents[lines]` to be able to read a char array into `contents[i]`.

Comment: That's one of the problem and by no means the first problem that the code encounters. And the suggested solution of declaring a `char *` array is incomplete as memory would need to be allocated for each entry.